# Windows 10 doesn't show up on grub bootloader

Tags: linux, windows-10, grub

I have installed a linux distribution alongside windows 10. Now when I turn on my pc all what I see is the linux distro on grub bootloader. I thought that grub would make choosing an OS to boot from of the two possible.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the distro. For Ubuntu, for example, the setup screen should have looked like this:

[image: Dual Boot Ubuntu Setup]

If one accidentally picks the second or third option, it can wipe out the Windows partition. Assuming you've *not* done that, then the easiest approach is to reinstall Linux from Live media, assuming you've not done much to modify Linux after installing. If all goes well, you *should* have a menu similar to that below.

[image: Grub Dual Boot options]

If the original Linux installation *has* destroyed Windows, then the only practical option is to restore from a recent image or from Windows installation media. [Recovering a deleted or modified partition is difficult, at best.]

Answer (score 0):

After some time, I realized that I have booted the linux cd with UEFI while windows boots from BIOS legacy. I used the windows installation media to fix the MBR and then reinstalled kali with BIOS legacy and now both OSs are shown from grub. Though when booting the win installation media, I booted with UEFI to do the "bootrec.exe /fixmbr". Will this result in a problem in the future?